# How to put grid line over bar in a Range bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

This is my gantt chart build for SSRS 2008 R2.
[image]

You can see light gray vertical lines on the third row, but not on the other lines. This is because these lines are draw under the bar (green and orange). My request is, how to draw these lines (Grid Lines) over bars (green and orange)?

Each line in my Tablix is a chart of type "Range, Bar", but all are on the same time frame.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the ZIndex of the Bar and Range chart?

Highlight the chart hit [F4] and the setting will be at the bottom of the properties tab.    Set the ZIndex of the **Bar**  lower than **Range**.

Comment: I checked multiple part of the chart properties: Chart: Zindex = readOnly, Chart GridLine: no ZIndex, Chart Series: No ZIndex.

Comment: Sorry, should have delved a little deeper, My apologies.  Have you tried re-ordering the declarations of each chart?  Maybe the render order is dependant on the order of where the charts appear in the XML?

Comment: Sorry, I think I poorly explained my issue, I edited my request. There is no chart in the chart, so I can't reorder this way...